# This question is related to mathematical expansions

Tags: polynomials

Can I get a proof of following Statement
For every natural number n, $ (x^n - a^n) $ is always divisible by $ (x-a) $.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: If $a$ is a root of a polynomial then $x-a$ divides the polynomial

Comment: or $(x^n-a^n)=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1})$

Comment: Have you tried long division of polynomials?

Comment: Thank you sir for suggestion. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

$(x^n-a^n)=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1}).$

This is a case of the [Polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), where $f(x)=x^n-a^n:$

$f(a)=0,$ so the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$ is $0$.

Comment: The polynomial remainder theorem, and the multinomial remainder following from the binomial theorem.